# How do change my program so that it always rounds to the nearest 2 decimal places)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

#.This program will find the area and perimeter of a circle with a radius given by the user.

import math

radius=int(input('enter a number for radius'))

area=math.pi*radius*2

print('area of circle %f'%area)

perimeter= 2*math.pi*radius

print('perimeter of circle %f'% perimeter)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `%f`, use `%.2f` when printing to round to two decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

Python has a round keyword. Use it like this:

```
round(3.14159, 2)
>>> 3.14
```

Alternatively, you can use python f-strings to round when printing, like this:

```
num = 3.14159
print(f'{num:.2f}')
>>> 3.14
```

Comment: Note: As of now, this question is tagged Python 2.7, and Python 2.7 doesn't support the f-string system.  If you are using Python 3, then f-strings are definitely the way to go.